# My python code is returning None even though the return value is not None

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I am working on a radix sort implementation that will sort a list of strings. It first compares the last character, then second to last, and so on using recursion. It returns the sorted list when it is done sorting off of the first character of the longest item.

```
if c == maxlength:
     print("returning")
     print(Out)
     return Out
```

The sorted list is stored in the `Out` list.
The above code prints out the sorted list exactly how it should using `Print(Out)`, but the function still returns `None`

Full code is below:

```
def grc(s, c):
    x = bytes(s, 'ascii')
    if c < len(s):
        temp = len(s) - (1 + c)
        return x[temp]
    elif c >= len(s):
        return x[0]

def radix(I, c = 0):
        Count = [0] * 128
        Out = [0] * len(I)

        for x in I:     #iterates over each item in the input array
            i = grc(x, c)
            Count[i] = Count[i] + 1

        for x in range(1, 128):
            Count[x] += Count[x-1]

        x = len(I) - 1
        while x >= 0:
            temp = I[x]
            tempbyte = grc(temp, c)
            Count[tempbyte] -= 1
            Out[Count[tempbyte]] = temp
            x -= 1
        
        maxlength = len(max(I, key=len)) - 1
        print("c: " + str(c) + ' Maxlen: ' + str(maxlength))
        if c == maxlength:
            print("returning")
            print(Out)
            return Out
        else:
            print("Recurring - current c: " + str(c))
            c += 1
            radix(Out, c)



def main():
    z = ['az', 'va', 'dc', 'zb', 'jb']
    result = radix(z)
    print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: When `if c == maxlength` evaluates to `False`, nothing is returned. That must be what's happening. Have you stepped through the program in a debugger to check why that's happening?

Comment: I know for a fact that isn't happening because the `print(Out)` still occurs

. Also the `c` value is incremented from 0 so it will always eventually equal `maxlength`

Comment: `radix(Out, c)` should be `return radix(Out, c)`. Recursive function calls must `return` their value.

Comment: That did it Axe319. Thank you!

Comment: Random Davis has the correct assessment. Also, your other function can also exit without returning a value. I searched on Stack Overflow for 'Check whether all control flow paths return a value' and saw only non-Python posts, so that may be a worthwhile follow up post.